# Proper way to submit a password

Tags: forms, vue.js, post, passwords

i'm using VueJS and sending in my username and password HTTPS to my backend endpoint....
trouble is I can see the password in the Chrome Inspector which seems not that safe?

Am I handling things wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending it with HTTPS you are doing it right. All communications between your authentication service and the client are encrypted.

An attacker is normally someone sitting between your browser and the service, not someone who can inspect your HTTP request like you did in your Chrome developer tools.

If you still don't feel comfortable about this, launch any login page of the well-known applications, for example, github.com and do Inspect, you will see password transferred without encryption.